# Replicating uploaded images stored in filesystem

Tags: file-upload, replication, application-server

Hi I am currently writing an application that allows users to upload images, which are stored on the filesystem with a reference in the database. However I have multiple application servers which these files need to be replicated to.

What are common methods for doing something like this? Are there any particularly good tools/scheme I can implement to do this?

edit:formatting

Answer (score 0):

To replicate files, I would use `rsync`.

Replication of references in the database, assuming that you have multiple writers, may be more complicated and depends on the DBMS and reference assignation scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an existing file storage platform such as Amazon.com's S3.  It would allow you to server user's images directly from their service.